# UITableview cell data dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a `UITableView` in `ViewController1`,and I am passing the TableView cell content through the Array and display it.

```
_tableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2" ,@"3",@"4",nil];


cell.detailTextLabel.text=[_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now, that I have passed the data through statically, I want to implement it through a dynamic way by using Model Class.

How can I alter the Array through Model Class Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create Model Class like this

```
@Interface SomeClass: NSObject

@property(nonatomic, Strong) NString* someValue;
```

2) Add model objects in the Datasource array ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for(i=1,i<5,i++)
    {
        SomeClass *someObj =  [SomeClass alloc]init];
        someObj.someValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [_tableData addObject:someObj];
    }
}
```

3) In cell for Row set the data to textLabel

```
SomeClass *someObj = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = someObj.someValue
```

**Note** - I have the model objects with hard coded data. You can use the data from webservice or data from core data.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to do is to refresh your table view whenever your datasource array changes

```
_tableData = [....some value....];
[tableView reloadData];
```